# Clone Button in a View Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have to create a clone button in view page. And has to write aa action method to controller page.

```
public PageReference CloneCon() {
    Anchor__c c =[Select id from Anchor__c];
        Anchor__c Clone = c.Clone();
    insert clone;
    pagereference ref = new pagereference('/apex/Anchor’');
    ref.setRedirect(True);
    return ref; 
}
```

Comment: KIndly explain what is your query and what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

The clone method only copies fields in the APEX object instance; It does not copy all of the fields from the database. If you only query for the Id, the clone will also only have an Id. If you want to copy other fields, you will need to query for them.